# Reload bash_profile after script has ended

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I have a script which modifies several things in bash_profile. I want a to reload bash_profile after my script terminates.

The main idea is to be able to use the same terminal without any additional actions (manually sourcing bash_profile) right after termination of script.

P.S. I know how to source bash_profile manually and programatically. The main problem that if I source it in the script it modify environment only for script itself (and not the terminal in which it was run)

**Update 1**

The script is run on freshly installed OS X. As result, bashrc and bash_profile can't be modified BEFORE script runs.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a wrapper function for your script to .bashrc:

```
myscript() { /path/to/myscript && . ~/.bash_profile; }
```

Comment: The script is run on freshly installed OS. As result, bashrc and so on aren't modified BEFORE script runs.

Comment: Then I don't see that you have a choice except to manually `source` it.